# (A logic question) I think its the right answer, but my explanation could be a bit more precise?

Tags: logic

Is (A & B & ~C) a sentence of Sentential Logic?

Answer: It is not because there needs to be at least one parentheses out side of two sentences connected by an ampersand.

Is this explanation correct?

Comment: But if you know that & is associative, you really don't need parentheses. Unless what you have in mind is "Is the sentence a Well Formed Formula?" and that you tell us what rules a WFF must follow in the formal logic you are studying.

Comment: Yes, I didn't clear it up initially, but the question is referring to WFF. The rule is this: If P and Q are sentences of SL, then (P & Q) is a sentence of SL. So by this rule then, if  A and B are sentences, then (A&B) is a sentence of SL. By repeating this rule then we have the following: if (A&B) and ~C are both sentences, then (A&B)&~C is a sentence.

Comment: Of course there should be an outer parentheses, namely, [(A&B)~C] , can be omitted, but in the textbook i'm learning, this is an informal rule.

Comment: I think it depends on the rules stipulated by your text. Since dropping the outermost parentheses is allowed, then dropping parentheses due to associativity is conceivably legal too, since both choices are systematic and for readability. Admittedly the former is a little more straightforward to implement.

Comment: Your concern and your comment together give the correct answer: details depend on the specifications of the formal syntax. IF the specification says: $(A \land B)$ with parentheses, then...